# @extend works only partially

Tags: html, css, sass

## @extend works only partially *or* Issue with @at-root inside of @extend - [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/YzqaZQe)

---

So - I've been quickly typing some animation to highlight an anchor tag by extending its underline to full height on hover with the help of Sass, but that's beside the point.

My goal is to extend the `a.link [&.link {…}]` and `.link [@at-root .link {…}]` class selector from *within* the parent `a` tag.

```
a {
  &.link { @extend %animation--anchor; }

  @at-root .link { @extend %animation--anchor; }
}
```

This works, unless I add a `&:hover` pseudo selector to my silent class, then it won't extend any pseudo class/selector. I know that when using the `@extend` directive on multiple elements it will work. So we can kinda isolate the cause of the issue to the `@at-root .link` selector.

---

Here is what it compiles to **without** a pseudo class/selector

```
a.link, .link {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #2196f3;
}
```

What it compiles to **with**

```
a.link, .link {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #2196f3;
}
.link:hover::before {
  height: 100%;
}
.link::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: height 500ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.2, 1.5);
}
```

---

Here is the code in question

```
$disable-inherited-anchorStyling: true;

$anchor--underlineColor: #2196f3;
$transition--short: 500ms;
$transition--in-out: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.2, 1.5);

%animation--anchor {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px $anchor--underlineColor;

  &:hover::before {
    height: 100%;
  }

  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: $anchor--underlineColor;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: height $transition--short $transition--in-out;
  }
}

a {
  @if ($disable-inherited-anchorStyling) {
    color: inherit;

    &:focus {
      outline: 0;
    }
  }

  &.link { @extend %animation--anchor; }

  @at-root .link { @extend %animation--anchor; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you’re trying to do isn’t possible.

The `@extend` rule only extends simple selectors. That’s why `@at-root .link` works but `&.link` doesn’t.

Take a look here at the limitations of the `@extend` rule:

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend#limitations